# Can't find sftp in XBMC

Tags: xbmc, sftp

According to http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=SFTP , SFTP should be available in XBMC, but I tried the current version available in the Ubuntu official repository (11.0) as well as 10.1, and it's just not there! I have all the other protocols like FTP, WebDAV, SMB and so on.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with xfce.